# Preg difference between /^a|b|c$/ and /^a$|^b$|^c$/

Tags: php, regex

To me they look the same... why are they different in practice?

```
echo preg_match("/^a|b|c$/", "aaaa");
```

echos 1

and `echo preg_match( "/^a$|^b$|^c$/", "aaaa");`

echos 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the first one to be exactly the same as the second one you must use a group:

```
echo preg_match("/^(a|b|c)$/", "aaaa");
```

[Regex example](https://regex101.com/r/2Y8NuF/1/)

Otherwise it means it has to match `^a` or `b` or `c$`

Comment: what a stupid mistake.. thanks

Comment: You only learn by making mistakes.

Comment: `^[abc]$` is better

Answer (score 3):

`/^a|b|c$/` matches all values starting with "a", containing "b" or ending with "c".
`/^a$|^b$|^c$/` matches just "a" or "b" or "c" and no other values.

```
echo preg_match("/^a|b|c$/", "aaaa"); // 1
echo preg_match("/^a|b|c$/", "zbaa"); // 1
echo preg_match("/^a|b|c$/", "aaac"); // 1

echo preg_match("/^a$|^b$|^c$/", "aaaa"); // 0
echo preg_match("/^a$|^b$|^c$/", "zbaa"); // 0
echo preg_match("/^a$|^b$|^c$/", "aaac"); // 0

echo preg_match("/^a$|^b$|^c$/", "a"); // 1
echo preg_match("/^a$|^b$|^c$/", "b"); // 1
echo preg_match("/^a$|^b$|^c$/", "c"); // 1
echo preg_match("/^a$|^b$|^c$/", "d"); // 0
```

[**demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/Iew3cb)